# Add-on for VB6 to find all references, etc?

Tags: vb6

I was working with VB6 last year and I used an Add-on that made it possible to search not only for the definition of objects or functions but also find all references or calls of specific objects or functions.

Unfortunately I can't remember where I got it from. Can anybody help on that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[MZTools](http://www.mztools.com/).

It is the *essential* free tool for all VB6 and VBA developers.

Comment: How can you get the `Find All References` right click menu item with MZTools?